# Truffle Migrate Endless Run

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am trying to deploy my contracts with

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
const Market = artifacts.require("Market");


module.exports = function (deployer, accounts) {
  
  deployer.deploy(Migrations, {from: accounts[0]});
  deployer.deploy(Market, {from: accounts[0]});
};
```

But, when I try to run the `truffle migrate` command, the editor gets its stack filled and I have to manually shut it down. I know that the problem is from the `{from: accounts[0]}` part, but I need to deploy them by this and this address only. What could you suggest?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a local blockchain, no one is mining so the block never arrives and it's just waiting for something to happen.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but when the ganache is open, the same problem occurs. And it successfully mines the blocks and deploys the contracts when I remove {from: accounts[0]} parts from each line.